# python3-pip No module named pip._main_: "pip is a package

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, debian

I am trying to develop a discord bot in python so i need to install the discord.py lib. My python3 version is python3.2.3
When I'm typing this command

> python3 -m pip install -U discord.py

I'm having the following issue

> /usr/bin/python3: No module named pip.**main**; 'pip' is a package and cannot be directly executed

I don't know if this can help you but i have 4 versions of Python in my debian server.
Python2.6, Python2.7, Python3, Python3.2

Comment: pip normally gets a standalone executable to run, does that work?

Comment: What do you mean ? I'm not sure to get it ?

Comment: Does `pip install discord.py` works? It looks like you don't have pip installed

Comment: apt-get install python3-pip tells me it's already installed

Comment: Command not found

Comment: `pip3 install discord.py`...not `pip install discord.py`.

Comment: Your pip isn't correctly installed, run the following command in your terminal `python3 -m ensurepip --default-pip`, this will install a version of pip for the current python.

Comment: @abccd this could be an issue with conflicting python interpreters. The author says he's running `python3.2` & `python3` but doesn't say anything about virtual environments.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/dev/installing/index.html#work-with-multiple-versions-of-python-installed-in-parallel

Answer (score 2):

Try installing pip using apt

```
sudo apt install python-pip python3-pip
```